# Commandbar Code Works In Standard Module But Not In "ThisWorkbook" Module

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have a procedure that creates a `CommandBar` with 5 controls. The first control button works perfectly, but the macros called by the 3 sub-buttons of the second control button show the following error on button click: `Cannot run the macro Heavy MX C D check status 2018 Rev 28 2019 Rev 1 January 2019 Working.xlsb'!SubName'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.` I have ensured that all macros are Enabled so that isn't the issue.

That Being Said, My Controls/Buttons are set up as follows:

- First control: A button, called *Get Transactions*. This control works perfectly in the `ThisWorkbook` module and the standard module.
- Second Control: A popup called *Sheet Actions* that houses three subcontrol buttons. This is where the issue lies. I have subprocedures which are called by the `OnAction` property when the any of the 3 sub-buttons are clicked, but I am receiving the aforementioned error. Each sub is called by each of the 3 buttons are placed directly below the `CreateToolbar` sub in the `ThisWorkbook` Module. I have already tried the following formats for `OnAction` with no success:

  - `OnAction = "SubName"`
  - `OnAction = "'SubName'"`
  - `OnAction = ' & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!SubName"`

Pictures of Controls:

[image]

[image]

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CreateToolbar()
'called from Workbook Open event procedure
 Dim Cbar As CommandBar
 Dim CbarControl As CommandBarControl
 Dim CbarControlSub1 As CommandBarControl
 Dim CbarControlSub2 As CommandBarControl
 Dim CbarControlSub3 As CommandBarControl

 'Get rid of any existing toolbar
 Application.CommandBars(sToolbarName).Delete

 '*************************************************************
 'This works as inteneded
 Set Cbar = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=sToolbarName)
    'Create the new toolbar
    With Cbar
            'Add a toolbar command button
            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!GetTransactions"
                .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Shift+G"
                .Caption = "Get Transactions"
                .Style = msoButtonCaption
                .TooltipText = "Click to Import and Categorize transactions."
            End With

        .Visible = True
        .Position = msoBarTop

    End With

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="GetTransactions", _
                         HasShortcutKey:=True, _
                         ShortcutKey:="G"

    Application.OnKey "^+g", "GetTransactions"
    '*************************************************************


   '*************************************************************
   'This is where I am having issues
   Set CbarControl = Cbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
   CbarControl.Caption = "Sheet Actions"

   Set CbarControlSub1 = CbarControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With CbarControlSub1
           .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
           .Caption = "Filter For New Transations"
           .OnAction = "FilterForNewTrans"
           .BeginGroup = True
        End With

        Set CbarControlSub2 = CbarControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With CbarControlSub2
           .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
           .Caption = "Clear Transaction Filter"
           .OnAction = "ClearFilter"
           .BeginGroup = True
        End With

        Set CbarControlSub3 = CbarControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With CbarControlSub3
               .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
               .Caption = "Clear Row Fill Color"
               .OnAction = "ClearFillColor"
               .BeginGroup = True
        End With
   '*************************************************************

End Sub
```

Any ideas, suggestions, or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write `Public Sub CreateToolbar()` instead of `Private Sub CreateToolbar()`?

Comment: @Vityata I actually tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work as hoped. That being said, I just now tried pulling the `CreateToolbar` sub along with the sub procedures for the buttons into a standard module and left them as private. In the `ThisWorkbook` Module, which fires on `Workbook_Open`, I changed `Call CreateToolbar` to `Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!CreateToolbar"` and it works like I need it to. I'd still like to know why in the world it won't work in `ThisWorkbook` Though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get the code to run in the `ThisWorkbook` Module, however I did get it to work in a standard module. I pulled the CreateToolbar sub along with the sub procedures for the buttons into a standard module and left them as private. In the ThisWorkbook Module, which fires on `Workbook_Open`, I changed `Call CreateToolbar` to `Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!CreateToolbar"` and it works as intended. For the Subs that are run on button click, I used `Application.OnKey "somekeycombination", "SomeSubName"`.

The following is the final code for the `CommandBar` with additional buttons:

```
Private Sub CreateToolbar()
 'called from Workbook Open event procedure
 Dim Cbar As CommandBar 'ToolBar

 Dim CbarControl_1 As CommandBarControl
 Dim CbarControl_2 As CommandBarControl
 Dim CbarControl_3 As CommandBarControl

 Dim ControlSubA1 As CommandBarControl
 Dim ControlSubA2 As CommandBarControl

 Dim ControlSubB1 As CommandBarControl
 Dim ControlSubB2 As CommandBarControl
 Dim ControlSubB3 As CommandBarControl
 Dim ControlSubB4 As CommandBarControl
 Dim ControlSubB5 As CommandBarControl


  'Get rid of any existing toolbar
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.CommandBars(ToolbarName).Delete

    '**************************************
    'Add the Toolbar
    '**************************************
    Set Cbar = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=ToolbarName)
    With Cbar
           .Visible = True
          .Position = msoBarTop
    End With
    '**************************************

'********************************************************************
'Button1
'********************************************************************
     Set CbarControl_1 = Cbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
         CbarControl_1.Caption = "Get Transactions"
    '**************************
    'SubButton1: Ctrl+Shift+G
    '**************************
            Set ControlSubA1 = CbarControl_1.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                With ControlSubA1
                   .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                   .Caption = "Import/Categorize ALL RECENT transactions"
                   .OnAction = "GetCurrMonTransactions"
                   .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Shift+G"
                   .BeginGroup = True
                   Application.OnKey "^+g", "GetCurrMonTransactions"
                End With

    '**************************
    'SubButton2: Ctrl+Shift+P
    '**************************
            Set ControlSubA2 = CbarControl_1.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                With ControlSubA2
                   .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                   .Caption = "Import/Categorize PREVIOUS MONTH'S transactions"
                   .OnAction = "GetPrevMonthTransactions"
                   .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Shift+P"
                   .BeginGroup = True
                   Application.OnKey "^+p", "GetPrevMonthTransactions"
                End With
    '********************************************************************
    '********************************************************************


'********************************************************************
'Button 2: Ctrl+Shift+U
'********************************************************************
    Set CbarControl_2 = Cbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
           With CbarControl_2
               .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!UploadTransToSQL"
               .Caption = "Save To SQL"
               .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Shift+U"
               .Style = msoButtonCaption
               .TooltipText = "Click to Export updated transactions to the SQL Server"
               Application.OnKey "^+u", "UploadTransToSQL"
           End With
    '********************************************************************
    '********************************************************************


'********************************************************************
'Button 3
'********************************************************************
    Set CbarControl_3 = Cbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    CbarControl_3.Caption = "Sheet Actions"

        '************************* 
        'SubButton1: Ctrl+Shift+F
        '*************************
        Set ControlSubB1 = CbarControl_3.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            With ControlSubB1
               .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
               .Caption = "Filter For New Transations"
               .OnAction = "FilterForNewTrans"
               .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Shift+F"
               .BeginGroup = True
               Application.OnKey "^+f", "FilterForNewTrans"
            End With

        '************************* 
        'SubButton2: Ctrl+Shift+O
        '*************************
        Set ControlSubB2 = CbarControl_3.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            With ControlSubB2
               .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
               .Caption = "Filter for Old Updated Transactions"
               .OnAction = "FilterForOldUpdates"
               .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Shift+O"
               .BeginGroup = True
               Application.OnKey "^+o", "FilterForOldUpdates"
            End With

        '*********************** 
        'SubButton3: Ctrl+Alt+c
        '***********************
        Set ControlSubB3 = CbarControl_3.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            With ControlSubB3
                .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                .Caption = "Clear Transaction Filters"
                .OnAction = "ClearFilter"
                .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Alt+c"
                .BeginGroup = True
                Application.OnKey "^%c", "ClearFilter"
            End With

    '************************
    'SubButton4: Ctrl+Alt+r
    '************************
        Set ControlSubB4 = CbarControl_3.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            With ControlSubB4
               .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
               .Caption = "Clear Row Fill Color"
               .OnAction = "ClearFillColor"
               .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Alt+r"
               .BeginGroup = True
               Application.OnKey "^%r", "ClearFillColor"
            End With

    '************************ 
    'SubButton5: Ctrl+Alt+a
    '************************
        Set ControlSubB5 = CbarControl_3.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            With ControlSubB5
               .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
               .Caption = "Toggle formula Auto-Calculations"
               .OnAction = "TurnOnAutoCalc"
               .ShortcutText = "Ctrl+Alt+a"
               .BeginGroup = True
               Application.OnKey "^%a", "TurnOnAutoCalc"
            End With
'********************************************************************
'********************************************************************

End Sub
```

And the code in the `ThisWorkbook` Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!CreateToolbar"

End Sub


'When this workbook is the active workbook, the toolbar will be enabled and show up
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application.CommandBars(ToolbarName)
         .Enabled = True
         .Visible = True
     End With
End Sub


'When the user activates another workbook, this disables the command bar
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application.CommandBars(ToolbarName)
         .Enabled = False
         .Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```